# Restrict Api Access

Tags: reactjs, api, token, parse-server, next.js

I make a web site with next.js and it retrieve it's data from a parse server, the problem is that i want to restrict my parse server api to be accessed only by my website i thought if i can generate a secret key or a token the moment the client hits the web page and send it to the parse server (the web site and parse server live in different places) and pass it to the website so the parse server on every request check for this key and it's validity and decide whether it accept the client or not, i want to know if this is a good idea or if there is a better way to do this.

**EDIT:**

my question is how to secure my api and be accessed only by my website,
i find something on restricting domain by allowing only your domain to access your api but the javascript execute in the client and there is no fixed domain.
so i thought if i generate a token and pass it to the client and send it to the parse server.

The client connect to the parse server with this token and if the token is valid that's ok the parse server accept it and give it data else it reject the client, and the client can't generate a token wile it is generated in the server side of the website(my next.js website with custom routes so there is a express server and it is possible to do some work before sending the page to the client).

finally please tell me if this method is good and if it is not what is the best way to secure an api like this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: well i'm not having problem with the code i'm asking if the concept is ok to work with i still dont write any code about key exchange